# How to to set width automatically?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a wrapper(container) with (from 2 to 4 div inside) like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

my problem is that I CAN'T set the width for the inner divs, because they must have an equals width, so if my wrapper is 300px and I only have two inner divs (150px once) etc etc.

But I can't set the width into .css file, because as i told there can be from 2 to 4 divs.

The question is: is it possible to autosize the inner divs (to get the entire wrapper's width) or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display:table` property for this:

```
.wrapper{
    width:300px;
    border:2px solid green;
    display:table;
}
.wrapper > div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7E9Nj/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using the percents? If you have 2 divs, put `style="width:50%"` on each div. If you have 4 divs, put `style="width:25%"` on each div.

Comment: yes I can do it, but is not possible without it? I mean... can they autosize automatically without setting the % ?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try % in your inner div's

for example, you could have something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="width:25%"></div>
    <div style="width:25%"></div>
    <div style="width:25%"></div>
    <div style="width:25%"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery. This will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var divWidth = parseInt($('.wrapper').css('width'));
var divSizes = parseInt($('.wrapper >div').size());
var divWidth = divWidth/divSizes;

$('.wrapper >div').each(function(){
$(this).css('width', divWidth+'px')
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply

```
#wrapper > div {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
}
```